# Why read-only transaction timeouts in Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to run some complex SQL queries on Google Cloud Spanner to evaluate its analytical perfomance. I've been using command-line tool (`gcloud spanner databases execute-sql`) and python client library (specifically `snapshot.execute_sql` method), and in both cases I'm getting a timeout after around 25 minutes. In python case (which I'm more interested in) I am not even getting an error message - the CPU activity of an instance becomes 0, and client just hangs waiting for the result.

Spanner docs does not explicitly say that read-only transactions does not have timeout, but one stackoverflow answer claims it ([Way to prevent transaction timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312793/way-to-prevent-transaction-timeout))

So, basically my question is: Is there really a timeout for SQL execution on the server side of a Spanner? If yes how to tune it, if no what can be the reason of the stated problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is due to Cloud Spanner's garbage collector that reclaims old versions of data by removing deleted or out of date data versions. According to the documentation, the garbage collector deletes versions older than 1 hour. This also means that a transaction can never read data versions older than 1 hour, effectively also putting a timeout of 1 hour on all (read-only) transactions.

See this part of the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/TransactionOptions, and then especially the **Old sessions.read Timestamps and Garbage Collection** part.

---

EDIT: Cloud Spanner now supports setting a version retention period that will allow you to query data with a staleness of more than 1 hour. See https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/timestamp-bounds#maximum_timestamp_staleness

Comment: Does it mean, that Spanner garbage collects intermediate results of the query? Is there a way to tune garbage collection interval?

Comment: When you issue a query, you also implicitly or explicitly start a transaction. All reads in this transaction will read data at a specific timestamp (your transaction timestamp). Cloud Spanner is not garbage collecting intermediate results of your query, but Cloud Spanner is garbage collecting data that your query has not yet read, but still needs to read. As far as I know, there is no possibility to tune this. This is also something you should not want to do. Having a transaction that lasts for more than 1 hour, also means that you will be locking the data for more than 1 hour.

Comment: Poideshь v futbik igratь?

Comment: Note: Read-only transactions will not take any locks, so the above comment that this transaction would take locks for up to 1 hour is incorrect.